# How can I change a tag to a different tag when the mouse is hovering the tag?

Tags: css, html, tags

Let's say for example I have an image of a dog. How do I make when the user hovers over the image, the image disappears and instead has the h1 tag that says "bark"?

Comment: you can have a container div, inside it have two divs for image and text. show/hide based on what you need. This is the idea, you can share some to help better

Comment: Overlap the image over the text, and then put a hover style on the image which hides it.

Comment: @techLove I never really thought about it that way. I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp) have some interesting examples

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code snippet can be a solution

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  #wrap {
   width: 128px;
   height: 128px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
  }
  #img {
   width: 128px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 0;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  #img:hover {
   opacity: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
 <h1>Bark!</h1>
 <img id="img" src="https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/o_collection_png/green_dark_grey/256x256/plain/dog.png">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code snippet can point you in the right direction:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img, h1 {
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
h1 {
    display: none;
}
img:hover + h1 {
    display: block;
}
h1:hover + img {
    display: none;
}
img:hover {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/jsdLHHv.png" />
<h1>Bark</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through different methods. For my example below on hover on the container it changes the "visibility" property. See sample code below.

```css
.animal-cont{
   width: 16%;
      height: 120px;
      border: 3px #ddd solid;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
    h1 {
      left: 50% ;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      color: #843f15;
  }
    img {
     max-width: 100%;
    }
    .animal-cont:hover > img {
   visibility: hidden;
  }
    .animal-cont:hover > h1 {
   visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<div class="animal-cont">
 <h1>Bark!</h1>
 <img id="img" src="">
</div>
```